# TV not detected by Windows/VGA - when there is a WHDI device in the signal chain

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, tv

I'm at my wit's end with this one...

I had an EVGA GTS 250, and I used to plug it's HDMI out into a WHDI sender, which transmitted to its corresponding WHDI receiver 15ft away, which then connected to a  Samsung LN40D LCD TV through another HDMI cable.

PC/VGA <> [hdmi cable] <> WHDI sender <[air]> WHDI receiver <> [hdmi cable] <> TV

It was perfect, stable, no perceivable latency. I just plugged everything the first time and it worked instantly. 
It sent 5.1 audio, and Windows/nVidia Control Center detected the TV by its name.
The WHDI device is this one: http://goo.gl/Q8iWI5

Now I bought an EVGA GTX 650, and WHDI doesn't work anymore. 
Both Windows and nVidia Control Center won't detect the TV, only the monitor that's connected via DVI. The TV screen shows "TX202913 connected. Check video signal." on top of a black screen. 
Though the device is not the problem itself, just the fact that it's not allowing direct connection between PC and TV. I would bet that if put an AVR in its place I'd also have this issue.

The HDMI on this new card works with other monitors. If I put the older card back, WHDI works normally.

I have googled this for 5 months on and off. Once I bumped into a page that showed how to force a display device to always-on through registry edit. Once I restarted windows, the Tv (through WHDI) displayed my expanded or duplicated desktop at 1024x768 **ONLY**, and listed the display as "digital display". I could not change the resolution and it wouldn't playback audio (although the option was available at nVidia Control Center HDMI audio options, but did not work). This proves that there is no conflict between the devices, except that software-wise, Windows cannot, for the life of it, understand that there's a TV there to send video/audio to.
Since this won't do (no audio, poor video), I reverted this regedit.

It's also not an EDID problem within the TV, since when connected directly it works.

The last weird bit of this saga is that today, I reminded of Windows' "Add Device" dialog, gave it a go, and a "Samsung Generic UPNP TV" showed up, which I promptly installed the drives for, rising to a climax of... ...NOTHING HAPPENING. As far as I can tell, it really didn't change anything other than using up a few kb in my main disc.

I should also say that I looked a LOT into handshake problems and nothing applied either.

Do any of you have an idea of what may be going on? I can't stand the thought of having a us$200 device not working because of the addition of a newer graphics card, when the much older one had no issues. 
There is absolutely NO REASON for this to happen.
There is NO documentation on WHDI online. Apparently no one buys this stuff. 
For the same reason, no one responded to this same plea for help on NVidia and EVGA forums.

Worst case, this can be a warning about this setup for people in the future.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

EDID can be the problem, because that info must be recived in graphic card from TV. I dont really know how your WHDI works but i had same problems with FC sender and DVI. You can read carefully WHDI manual because probably it has some "learning monitor" function, so WHDMI can read EDID from TV and send it to your graphic card.